# How to import okhttp library to android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, okhttp

I want to import okhttp source code (not jar) to android studio as a module. Any suggestions on that ? Thanks !

Answer (score 27):

Unless you just need the source code for some reason in your app, you can just add it as a library by adding

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.12.0'
```

to your Gradle build script or

```
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.12.0")
```

for kts.

Comment: Now `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'`

Comment: December 2016. The line for the latest version can be found at https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/README.md. It is currently line is `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0'`.

Comment: I am getting: `Error:(3, 0) Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

Answer (score 8):

Add this line to your Module level `build.gradle` script (Not project level):

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
}
```

Then click the build icon (green axe) on top right corner.

Answer (score 2):

Their source is available on Github: https://github.com/square/okhttp

Clone it to your machine, and import it into your project.

Answer (score 1):

`OkHttp` is a java project, you can use idea rather than Android studio.

1. open idea
2. project → open → select `pop.xml` in project root directory
3. wait for a while